# How to add live wallpaper in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to create an app in which I can add live wallpaper to the home screen. Is it possible in iOS 5?

If possible, then please help me how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, certainly not without jailbreak.

Comment: is it possible in ios 3 or ios 4??

Comment: No. And it’s quite unlikely to be supported in future versions, too.

Comment: But there is some apps for setting active/live wallpapers. How they do it?

Comment: Which ones? It’s probably something else than it looks like.

Comment: By installing Cydia  can  we able to set live wallpaper?

Comment: Cydia requires a jailbroken iPhone. If you want to distribute your app using the App Store, Cydia does not help.